# Minecraft Pocket Edition Local Multiplayer

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

After the 0.13.0 update on Minecraft Pocket Edition, me and my brother can't play Minecraft together.

I have an IOS device and he has an Android device and we are connected to the same WiFi.

I have tried connecting to other WiFi servers and we tried using different devices, but it still won't work! How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure "Multiplayer Game" is on. To turn it on, go to the main page (before you see your worlds), and go to settings and next to Multiplayer Game turn it on.

Once you turn it on, it should be white. Make sure both of you have it on. If Multiplayer Game does not work, then you do the same with "Broadcast to LAN". 
But I'm pretty sure it's Multiplayer Game.